# Excel Scenario Manager on Multiple Worksheets

Tags: excel, formulas, scenarios

I'm trying to use Scenario Manager across multiple worksheets.  I have all of my inputs on one worksheet and outputs on another.  I'd like to set up multiple scenarios of the inputs and then show the resulting cells (on the other worksheet) in the Scenario Manager Summary.  I can only find that it's possible if everything is on one worksheet.

Can someone assist?

Comment: this isn't necessarily an answer to your question, but more a general "good to know"... the scenario manager is one of the least integrated tools in excel. unless you have a lot of time and like to do hard work, you might want to look for specialiced add-ins. just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you just link the result cells from your second worksheet to the first one? This did the trick for me. Not the most elegant but a really simple solution.